# managing memory of an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, memory, parallel-processing

I have a model written in `R`.  This model seems to require `32 GB RAM`.  I want to run the model 200 times with `AWS-EC2`.  Initially I planned to use a `c5.12xlarge` `Spot Instance`.  The `c5.12xlarge` instance has `48 vCPUs` and `96 memory (GiB)`.  At first I thought I would be able to run the model 48 times simultaneously because of the `48 vCPUs`.  But now I am thinking I might only be able to run the model three times simultaneously because 32 x 3 = 96 matching the `96 memory (GiB)`.

If I submit 200 models at once will the instance immediately run out of `memory` and cause every model to crash or be `killed`?  Is there a way I can manage the `memory` used per model to prevent every model from crashing?

Here is the `R` code I use to implement `parallel processing`.  Can this code be modified to assign 32 GiB memory per model?

```
setwd('/home/ubuntu/')

library(doParallel)

detectCores()

my.AWS.n.cores <- detectCores()

registerDoParallel(my.cluster <- makeCluster(my.AWS.n.cores))


folderName <- 'model000222b'


files <- list.files(folderName, full.names=TRUE)

start.time <- Sys.time()

foreach(file = files, .errorhandling = "remove") %dopar% {
  source(file)
}

stopCluster(my.cluster)

end.time <- Sys.time()
total.time.c <- end.time-start.time
total.time.c
```

Should I simply modify the `R` code to only allow `3 cores` maybe using:

```
my.AWS.n.cores <- 3
```

Or will `AWS-EC` manage the `memory` behind the scenes so all 200 models are able to run without me specifying anything about number of `cores` or `memory` to be reserved per model?

If I can only use `3 cores` at once then perhaps I should select a difference `instance` type that has fewer `vCPUs` and more `GiB` of `memory`?  Perhaps I should even consider using an `x2iedn.4xlarge` instance with `16 vCPUs` and `512 GiB` memory?

Thank you for any suggestions on how to run this model 200 times efficiently on `AWS-EC2` given its large `memory` requirement.

Comment: Autoscaling based on memory?

Comment: @Riz  Thank you.  I will look into it.  I have never used autoscaling.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run `20` models simultaneously using a `r6a.48xlarge` instance (`192 vCPUs`, `1536.00 GiB` memory) and this `R` code:

```
setwd('/home/ubuntu/')

library(doParallel)

detectCores()

my.AWS.n.cores <- detectCores()
my.AWS.n.cores <- my.AWS.n.cores - 92
my.AWS.n.cores

registerDoParallel(my.cluster <- makeCluster(my.AWS.n.cores))


folderName <- 'model000222'


files <- list.files(folderName, full.names=TRUE)

start.time <- Sys.time()

foreach(file = files, .errorhandling = "remove") %dopar% {
  source(file)
}

stopCluster(my.cluster)

end.time <- Sys.time()
total.time.c <- end.time-start.time
total.time.c
```

Note that the above `R` code did not run until I reduced the number of `cores` to `100` from `192` with this line:

```
my.AWS.n.cores <- my.AWS.n.cores - 92
```

If I tried running the code with all `192 vCPUs` or `187 vCPUs` I got this `error message`:

```
> my.AWS.n.cores <- detectCores()
> my.AWS.n.cores <- my.AWS.n.cores - 5
> my.AWS.n.cores
[1] 187
> 
> registerDoParallel(my.cluster <- makeCluster(my.AWS.n.cores))
Error in socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, blocking = TRUE,  : 
  all connections are in use
Calls: registerDoParallel ... makePSOCKcluster -> newPSOCKnode -> socketConnection
```

I have never seen that `error message` before and could not locate it with an internet search.

Note also that when I tried installing `R` on this instance with the lines below in `PuTTY` I got a series of errors the last of which said `R` could not be found.  Those errors never arose with other instances I have used in the past with these same command lines.

```
sudo su
echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

To resolve this issue I had to run this line after which I guess `R` was installed correctly:

```
apt install r-base-core
```

I used this `AMI`:

```
Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type
```

Hopefully `40` models will run simultaneously. I have not yet tried.  I also will post a new question about the above `error message`.

**EDIT - September 27, 2022**

I have been able to use this approach to run `36` models simultaneously.  Also, with my most recent runs I have not had to use this line:

```
apt install r-base-core
```